# Object reference... in ProcessRequestMain. Fixed by recyclinx app pool, but looking for a permanent solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I'm using Asp.Net Identity 2.0 and the Login page loads without a problem, but after it gets redirected I get an error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Full StackTrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ConsultaMarcas._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +331
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

The weird part is that it only happens after some time that the page is running, if I recycle the app pool, everything works fine until it starts throwing the same error.

Here's the Page_Load that's causing trouble:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        lib.controlManipulator wom = new lib.controlManipulator();
        dDSedes = wom.getListaSedesDropDown(dDSedes);

        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var currentuser = manager.FindById(userID);
        List<string> sedes = currentuser.Sedes.Split(',').ToList();
        List<string> aRemover = new List<string>();

        foreach (string sede in sedes)
        {
            foreach (ListItem sedeDdl in dDSedes.Items)
            {
                if (sede != sedeDdl.Value && !sedes.Exists(x => x == sedeDdl.Value))
                {
                    aRemover.Add(sedeDdl.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string sedeaBorrar in aRemover)
        {
            dDSedes.Items.Remove(dDSedes.Items.FindByValue(sedeaBorrar));
        }

        dDSedes.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Seleccione una Sede--", "0"));
        dDSedes.Items.Insert(dDSedes.Items.Count, new ListItem("Todas las Sedes"));

        dDSedes.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 331?   There are lots of places in that code for a null reference.

Comment: There are only 77 lines.

Comment: Well, your stack trace shows an error at line 331 of your page code-behind; I'd suggest figuring out which line that is.

Comment: I don't know why it says that, because [this is all my code](http://pastebin.com/MHLbs5Nj)